How can I connect backend service with frontend using ingress in kubernetes
I have this ingress file which help me to be able to connect backend with frontend
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: avatars-app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app.test
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: frontend-app-service
              port:
                number: 5173
        - path: /api
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: backend-app-service
              port:
                number: 5000

But every time I try to enter to app.test (I expect to see my frontend) I get an empty response.
What I'm doing wrong
These are my deployments and servicces:
backend-app.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-app-deployment
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: backend-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: backend-app
          image: jtiradoxxx/avatares-devops-backend:v1.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          env:
            - name: FLASK_APP
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: backend-config
                  key: FLASK_APP
            - name: FLASK_ENV
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: backend-config
                  key: FLASK_ENV

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-app-service
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000

frontend.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend-app-deployment
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: frontend-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: frontend-app
          image: jtiradoxxx/avatares-devops-frontend:v1.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          env:
            - name: VITE_HOST
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: frontend-config
                  key: VITE_HOST
            - name: VITE_PORT
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: frontend-config
                  key: VITE_PORT

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend-app-service
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: frontend-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5173
      targetPort: 5173

I added my deployments to the same namespace and I can see that ingress' pods are running well. But I cannot use the frontend

It can be really tough to host them under the same hostname cause the URIs may conflict, and you may possibly see unexpected behaviors. I suggest you separate them at the hostname level. For example, host your backend at api.example.com and your frontend at app.example.com. You also have a rewrite in your Nginx, which can complicate things a bit further if you're not careful or you have conflicting endpoints on both of your upstream servers.

Bear in mind that if you really have to have them under the same host, you have to merge the two spec.rules as, at the moment, it is an array of two elements. Whereas you'd likely want them to merge them together to have spec.rules.host and spec.rules.http combined under one array element.

i believe you should match targetPort from service to the deployment port

Both Services' targetPort: don't match what you've declared as the Deployments' containerPort:.  What ports are the actual programs listening on?  (Using the standard HTTP port 80 for all of the Pods and Services is fine, because Kubernetes's internal networking layer gives each of these parts their own internal IP address.)

(I think it's fine to use the same external hostname for the front- and back-end services.  In particular, if this means you can use path-only URLs in your application, then you can avoid building it into the application, and you avoid CORS concerns.)

For completeness, using an Ingress may be redundant if the goal is to just connect frontend-app to backend-app within the same cluster.

I'd actually second the comment of @DazWilkin. Unless you explicitly want to make backend-appavailable to the outside of the cluster, there is little sense in using an ingress.
